# How to view Exchange safelist

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, spam

I've been able to update the Exchange safelist based on the user mailbox safelist with:

```
get-mailbox | where {$_.RecipientType -eq [Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Recipient.RecipientType]::UserMailbox } | update-safelist
```

But is there a way to actually view the safelist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125168.aspx) this should not be possible. The aggregated addresses are one-way hashed and then converted to binary for security purposes.

You can only hash given email with SHA-256 and then compare it to the values in the user's objects attribute **msExchSafeSenderHash** to see if it is the same, but that's about it.